# Python: not all arguments converted during string format

Tags: python, string, dataframe, formatting

I have a panel for 5 years. Each person `[aa_cod_fiscm]` declares his income `[cc_red_lrd]` each year. I am trying to have a difference of declaration between each year and the previous one `[difprev].` My code is

```
data["difprev"]= data.groupby(data.aa_cod_fiscm % 5).cc_red_lrd.diff()
```

All the variables are integers, but I get the following error

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I don't know why. Can you help me , please?

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is that the % is being evaluated as a formatter rather than a mod function because data.aa_cod_fiscm is evaluating as a str object. Maybe this is how it is stored in that attribute? You could try casting it to an int.

try this:

```
data["difprev"]= data.groupby(int(data.aa_cod_fiscm) % 5).cc_red_lrd.diff()
```

Comment: Hi, I tried and I got the following error: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

Comment: @Miki it seems like you're returning something that you're not expecting from data.aa_cod_fiscm

Do you know what type of object it is? You can use the built in type() method to find out like so:

`type(data.aa_cod_fiscm)`